# Trigger a button inside a link with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a set of images with some information like the author and now I'm adding a few buttons to allow users to like images.

Since the image has a link to the images screen I don't know how to trigger the button avoiding to fire the link.

Here is the code, I'm using Vuetify and Nuxt:

```
<nuxt-link
  :to="
    `/photo/${slotProps.item.id}/${
      slotProps.item.slug
    }`
  "
>
  <v-hover>
    <v-img
      slot-scope="{ hover }"
      :src="slotProps.item.url"
    >
      <v-fade-transition mode="in-out">
        <div
          v-if="hover"
          class="d-flex transition-fast-in-fast-out photo-overlay pa-2"
        >
          <div
            class="d-flex pl-1 credits justify-space-between align-center w-100"
          >
            <div>
              <nuxt-link
                :to="
                  `/user/${slotProps.item.pId}`
                "
                class="secondary--text body-2 d-inline-block"
              >
                <v-avatar size="30">
                  <img
                    :src="slotProps.item.avatar"
                    :alt="`${slotProps.item.name}`"
                  />
                </v-avatar>
                <span class="ml-2">
                  {{ slotProps.item.name }}
                </span>
              </nuxt-link>
            </div>
            <div>
              <v-menu
                v-model="addToGalleriesMenu"
                :close-on-content-click="false"
                :nudge-width="200"
              >
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <v-btn v-on="on" v-bind="attrs" icon color="secondary">
                    <v-icon small>
                      fal fa-hearth
                    </v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                </template>
                <v-card outlined>
                  <v-card-title>Test</v-card-title>
                </v-card>
              </v-menu>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-fade-transition>
    </v-img>
  </v-hover>
</nuxt-link>
```

The code above generate an image, on mouse hover a layer appear at the bottom showing the name and a button to like the image.

Clicking on the user link it works fine, as expected. Clicking on the button that should fire an action is not working because the image link get clicked.

How can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop event propagation to the parent element very easily using Vue click modifiers:

```html
<a href="example.com">
  ...  
  <v-btn @click.stop.prevent="test()">
   ...
```

You can achieve the same thing without using Vue modifiers:

```html
<a href="example.com">
  ...  
  <v-btn @click="test($event)">
   ...
```

```js
methods: {
  test (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, but how to deal with the v-on="on" where should I put the stopPropagation when I don't have a `@click` handler? Thanks

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo try to add the empty attribute: `<v-btn v-on="on" @click.stop.prevent="">`

Comment: I finally found the solution thanks to your snippet! Cheers!